# Android menu realization

Tags: android, android-menu

Iam newbie in Android development, and I have one stupid question.
Is all pretty menu from android applications it's just different pictures that changes on another pictures when somebody doing actions on them (click, hold, etc...)?
something like this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageId);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // changing picture here.
    }
});
```

And main question is which container do you use for them, just image? 
Where i can found some tutorials about creating menu for android that will look pretty.

For example [this menu](http://ognarevgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/CutnRoll_ognarevgames_menuMain_05.png)

Also i will be glad to see how you realized your menu(best practice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this example for creating menu [How to Create Android Menus](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/)

from android developer [Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) it describes types of menus available in andorid.

Customs menus like this

[Example one](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-game-menu-with-a-custom-font/)

[Example two](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-game-menus-in-android,518.html)

Comment: No i mean practice for creating this like menu http://ognarevgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/CutnRoll_ognarevgames_menuMain_05.png

Comment: those are custom menus,have to create by own as you want.that will be depends on the requirement..

Comment: But do you have some examples of realization these types of menus.